# USB Stick Creation

Tags: system-installation

CD Creator will not locate my USB Stick to create 12.4 LTS OS. I have followed instruction on this site but without CD Creator locating USB Stick I am dead in the water. Please Help

Comment: Hi, Randy. Please clarify, you're trying to use CD Creator to make a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS bootable USB? What version of Ubuntu (or operating system) is on your system?

Comment: I think this should be tagged "12.04" as well.

Comment: Try using the Startup Disk Creator or Unetbootin

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#From_Ubuntu_Linux

Answer (score 0):

I thought (on windows computer) you need to use [USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to make bootable USB stick.